# Model binding not working in aspnet core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am working on ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API project. I am trying to follow this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/ but I am stuck at Action. My model class just won't bind to the input.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginVM loginVM)
{
    IActionResult response = Unauthorized(); // cant reach this point, my breakpoint is here
    var user = AuthenticateUser(new UserModel { });

    if (user != null)
    {
        var tokenString = GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
        response = Ok(new { token = tokenString });
    }

    return response;
}

public class LoginVM
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So what is inside `// some code`? Are you sure it's not that giving you the error?

Comment: @DavidG I am unable to reach the breakpoint which is at first line in the method.

Comment: Can you add your main class declaration too? i'm assuming you've copied the `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and the `[ApiController]` too

Comment: @Sasha yes I did that but I have checked by placing break point in the constructor of the class, that point is reachable so I think routing is fine here.

Comment: Use `[FromForm]`. Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: @Nkosi ok this solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're posting as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you have the `[FromBody]` attribute applied to the action param. These two things are fundamentally incompatible. To accept `x-www-form-urlencoded` (or `multipart/form-data`) you must apply the `[FromForm]` attribute to the param. If you have `[FromBody]`, as you do now, then you can only accept something like `application/json` or `application/xml` (if you also enable the XML serializers).

If the issue is that you want to be able to accept both `application/json` *and* `x-www-form-urlencoded` request bodies, that is not possible. You'll need a separate action for each request body encoding, though you can factor out the actual meat of the action into a private method on the controller that both actions can utilize.

Answer (score 0):

Choose "raw" in Body and "Content-Type" as "application/json" in postman and then try.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See the comments attached to the question. Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.